# A word to describe something being large, beyond comprehension?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word or even scientific term to describe something being so large it is beyond rational comprehension?

Comment: Are you looking for a noun, or an adjective?

Comment: But scientists (specifically, pure mathematicians) routinely deal with numbers that are incredibly large. For example, imagine our entire universe was the equivalent of a single atom in a larger "containing" universe, then sum up all the "contained" atoms within that. Mathematicians comprehend perfectly well that - big as it is - that number is actually *closer to zero* than it is to an *infinite* number.

Comment: And, of course, mathematicians understand many different values of infinity.   (The technical term for that is ‘‘transfinite cardinals’’.)

Answer (score 1):

*Immeasurable* could suggest that it is beyond the scope of human measurement:

> incapable of being measured; limitless - [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/immeasurable?s=t)

Likewise *inordinate* could suggest something beyond normal limits:

> not within proper or reasonable limits; immoderate; excessive - [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inordinate?s=t)

*Prodigious* means extraordinarily large, but not so much so that it's beyond comprehension:

> extraordinary in size, amount, extent, degree, force, etc. - [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/prodigious?s=t)

Or you could simply add "incomprehensibly" or "numinously" before any adjective meaning large, e.g. "numinously massive", "incomprehensibly huge".

Comment: Please [cite quotations correctly](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). A link is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

> It is so large it is **imponderable**.

Imponderable:

> *adjective*
>   1. not ponderable; that cannot be precisely determined, measured, or evaluated. *noun*
>   2. an imponderable thing, force, agency, etc.

Source:  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imponderable)

Comment: Please [cite quotations correctly](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). A link is not enough, and there isn't even a link here.

Comment: @AndrewLeach aye aye and thanks ... i thought i had but obviously i did not!

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions.

The first, fitting your description *so large it is beyond rational comprehension*, is ***inconceivable***:

> *impossible to imagine or think of* ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inconceivable))

Or even just go straight for ***incomprehensibly*** big / numerous / etc.

One of the most appropriate adjectives (as it works in so many contexts), though, is ***astronomical***, which fits the sense of *scale* you evoked.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest '**immense**'.

> 1. Unmeasured; so great that it has not been or cannot be measured; immeasurably large; of boundless extent; infinite. ? Obs.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/91856?redirectedFrom=immense#eid)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

- [Infinite](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/infinite): Having no boundaries or limits; impossible to measure or calculate
- [Transcendent](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/transcendent): 1. Surpassing others; preeminent or supreme; 2. superior or supreme.
- [Inscrutable](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/inscrutable): Difficult to understand or interpret; impenetrable
- [Incomparable](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/incomparable): 1. Being such that comparison is impossible; incommensurable; 2. So outstanding as to be beyond comparison; unsurpassed.
- [Incommensurable](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/incommensurable): 1. Impossible to measure or compare; 2. Lacking a common quality on which to make a comparison.